# How to work with Git repositories without network connection?

Tags: git, repo

Supposing I have to work in an isolated subnetwork without connection to source repo. As start of development, I can do "git clone" in somewhere where has connection and then copy over ".git" directory by USB stick.

Then I can use this ".git" directory for local branching, committing etc. Then at some point, I need to contribute back my changes to source repo, i.e., I need to do "push" now. What is the best way to *push* to source repo by means of USB stick transport method? Ideally I would want to move a whole branch back to repo.

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch

Comment: you can send commits by email

Comment: [git bundle](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)

Comment: Will you then have access to the private subnetwork again ? Do you have contact with somebody that has access ? If anybody, you or a contact has access to this network + the USB stick, She can push to the isolated network things that were committed locally on the USB stick

Comment: This(git bundle) is the answer. Git is really powerful, thanks to Linus.

Comment: A very good reading about this topic, https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/10/bundles.html